# Calculos com data na consulta

Tags: mysql, data

Estou com uma dificuldade há algum tempo. Tenho pesquisado , mas não encontrei algo que me ajudasse.

Eu preciso fazer um calculo em uma consulta, é o seguinte. Eu preciso pegar o dia que o registro foi inserido no banco e depois fazer uma operação com a data atual, eu tenho que subtrair a data atual pela data que foi inserida no banco, se o valor da subtração for maior que 3 , eu saberei que essa registro esta atrasado. Então preciso fazer isso para cadas registro da minha tabela, e contar quantos estão atrasados. Eu sei que devo usar `COUNT(*)` , `DATADIFF`, `INTERVAL`, e por ai vai, mas não consegui. Isso é possível ? Como seria ? Obrigado.

Comment: Qual a estrutura de sua tabela?

Comment: Basicamente , tenho o codigo (int), NomeCLiente Varchar , Data_operacao (TIMESTAMP)

Comment: Você vai utilizar o DATEDIFF para ajudar na solução do problema. Aconselho dar uma acessada neste site: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_datediff.asp Só acompanhar o tutorial que você fica fera. Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(data_operacao, NOW()) AS Diferenca_Dias FROM Tabela
```

Daí na linguagem que você estiver utilizando você faz a verificação. Se o resultado que deu for maior que 3 está atrasado.

Comment: Primeiramente obrigado pela ajuda. Mas não teria como criar um count para ja me dar a quantidade? Estou preocupado com a performace, pois minha tabela é gigante. rs

Answer (score 2):

Segue um exemplo:

```
SELECT curdate() hoje, Data_operacao
, DATEDIFF(curdate(), Data_operacao) as dias
, (
case 
when DATEDIFF(curdate(), Data_operacao) <= 3 then 0
else (DATEDIFF(curdate(), Data_operacao) - 3)
end 
) dias_atraso
FROM NOME_SUA_TABELA
```

Total de atraso é só somar o total do retorno da tabela.

```
SELECT 
 sum(
case 
when DATEDIFF(curdate(), Data_operacao) <= 3 then 0
else (DATEDIFF(curdate(), Data_operacao) - 3)
end 
) as TOTAL_atraso
FROM NOME_SUA_TABELA
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Primeiramente obrigado pela ajuda. Mas não teria como criar um count para ja me dar a quantidade? Estou preocupado com a performace, pois minha tabela é gigante. rs

Comment: Atualizei a resposta com uma query com o total do atraso

Comment: Cara muito bom... So que tem um problema , ela está me retornando um valor errado, eu tenho 2 linhas atrasadas no banco , no final ele está me retornando 4, porquê será ?

Comment: Para isso precisaria conhecer sua situação mais detalhadamente.... pode montar um Fiddle? http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Te agradeço demais. So que infelizmente não vai dar tempo agora , pois terei que sair. Mas amanhã bem cedinho eu monto e te mostro. Valeu mesmo.